# Вывод страниц в меню WP

Tags: wordpress

Всем доброго дня, столкнулся с проблемой - делаю вывод страниц в меню по тематическим локациям, но в моем меню выводятся сразу же все страницы, которые созданы в админке. В header вывожу пункты меню таким образом:

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'theme_location' => 'Schedule&Fleet',
  'container' => false,
  'menu_class' => 'hidden-dropmenu',
  ) );
?>
```

в файле functions прописал:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
  product&services' => __('Product&services'),
  e-services' => __('eServices'),
  schedule&fleet' => __('Schedule&Fleet'),
  enquiry' => __('Enquiry'),
));
```

Но меню все равно выводит в списке абсолютно все страницы. В чем может быть проблема или что я упускаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `register_nav_menus()` регистрирует локации (области расположения). Для того, чтобы указать, что меню находится в заданной области, надо поставить галочку в админ-странице меню.

Если функция `wp_nav_menu()` не может найти меню в заданной локации, то она выводит первое меню, содержащее пункты (строка 106 в `/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php`).

Таким образом, чтобы код работал правильно, либо укажите нужное меню в нужной локации через админку, либо задайте параметр 'menu' в `wp_nav_menu()` с именем вашего меню. Во втором случае можно вообще отказаться от вызова `register_nav_menus()`.

Comment: я перепроверил, галочки для тем. локаций и меню у меня стоят, но WP все равно выводит все элементы меню.

Comment: Задайте параметр 'menu' в wp_nav_menus. Возможно, где-то ошибки с переводом или еще с чем-то.